# how to rostopic pub msg with array members

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i want to publish msg like this:

```
Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
Point point
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
```

i can use the following cmd:

```
rostopic pub pt geometry_msgs/PointStamped '{stamp: now, frame_id: base_link}' '[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]'
```

or
rostopic pub pt geometry_msgs/PointStamped '{stamp: now, frame_id: base_link}' '[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]'

what command should i use to publish **msgs with array members** like:

```
std_msgs/Header header
string[] joint_names
trajectory_msgs/MultiDOFJointTrajectoryPoint[] points 
       geometry_msgs/Transform[] transforms
       geometry_msgs/Twist[] velocities
       geometry_msgs/Twist[] accelerations
       duration time_from_start
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269695/how-to-rostopic-pub-msg-with-array-members/) by [peigong](https://answers.ros.org/users/31721/peigong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do it just as you filled the `Point`. For instance, if you want to fill the `joint_names` of a MultiDofJointTrajectory:

```
rostopic pub mdjt trajectory_msgs/MultiDOFJointTrajectory  '{joint_names:[name1, name2]}'
```

have a look at [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/10244/publish-arrays-to-a-topic-on-the-command-line/). It *is* a bit clunky (especially when the vectors you are trying to fill aren't simple types), so it's probably useful to play around a bit in a text editor. For a slightly more intricate example:

```
rostopic pub mdjt trajectory_msgs/MultiDOFJointTrajectory  '{joint_names:[name1, name2, name3], points:[{time_from_start: {secs: 1, nsecs: 100}}, {time_from_start: {secs: 100, nsecs: 300}}]}'
```

Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peigong](https://answers.ros.org/users/31721/peigong/) on 2017-08-28**:
Thank you for your kind reply.

it works.